# Powershell Scripting Error

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Push-Location
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location C:\
PS C:\> Set-Location HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
PS HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel> Set-ItemProperty .          TypeGuessRows "0"
PS HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel>
```

Above is my code.It works manually. But how to run the above script on server.
 When save my script in myscript.ps1 and try to execute getting below error

```
PS C:\> .\myscript.ps1
```

Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Push-Location'.
At C:\myscript.ps1:1 char:3
+ PS <<<<  C:\WINDOWS\system32> Push-Location
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Comment: What is the exact content of your script file?

Comment: My script file is in the code section

Comment: Does your script file actually contain the `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>` part and similar, or only the `Push-Location` and similar parts?

Comment: I am newbie. I just copied my script from powershell. It does have PS...The script is similar to the above

Comment: Your script should only have the commands you want it to run, i.e. `Push-Location` on the first line, `Set-Location C:\` on the second line and so forth.

Comment: I really shouldn't, but I did in my last comment. `Push-Location` on the first line, `Set-Location C:\\` on the second, etc. You really should be able to piece it together from that. I suggest reading a few scripts (I'm sure you can find lot's of them on the internet) since it could help you understand what they should look like. Best of luck!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend messing around in the registry until you are more familiar with powershell and its semantics. Powershell is an extremely powerful and potentially destructive tool that requires understanding before jumping in and modifying registry entries. I would recommend this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145389503.do it's great if you're just getting started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Push-Location
Set-Location C:\
Set-Location HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
Set-ItemProperty . TypeGuessRows "0"
```

It works with the above code...Robert thanks for your help...